# What is the rule when the ball touches both the bat and the batsman's body?

Tags: rules, cricket

- If a ball bowled to a batsman hits the bat first and then hits the pad/any part of the batsman's body, what is the rule on getting runs or boundaries or catch at this situation?
- If a ball bowled to a batsman hits the pad/any part of the batsman's body first and then hits the bat, what is the rule on getting runs or boundaries or catch at this situation?

We can see the above situations most of the times in international cricket matches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Catches, runs, and boundaries are all possible if the ball touches the bat at any point, regardless of what else the ball may go on to touch. Furthermore, if the ball hits the pad before the bat, an LBW dismissal may also be possible.

Only if the ball does not touch the batsman's person may Byes be scored ([Law 26.1](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-26-bye-and-leg-bye/)), and only if it touches the batsman's person but not bat may Leg byes be scored ([Law 26.2](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-26-bye-and-leg-bye/)) (an oversimplification, but sufficient for the purposes of this answer).

Once the ball has touched any part of the batsman's person, he/she may not intentionally strike it again (other than to protect his/her wicket), as this would mean he/she was out *hit the ball twice* ([Law 34)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-34-hit-the-ball-twice/).

Comment: @Spinner OK, clear. But now the ball is deflected (slightly, not intentionally in the sense of including the pad in the sequence) of the pad (assuming no LBW) to the bat and then to the boundary. Runs, leg byes or what? Must happen a lot, but can't recall an instance.

Comment: @Gugg Runs. Byes and leg byes only come into play if there is no contact with the bat, according to Law 26; it's not a question of what the ball first touched. (Note that leg byes need not touch the batsman's legs; leg byes may be scored off any part of the batsman's body, except the hand(s) holding the bat.)